# Querying Vertices through another vertex [GREMLIN]

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

[image: graph database]

The image above is how my graph looks like, and i would like to query the following output:

```
[
    {
        chart:{
            name: 'chart1',
            id: 'chart1',
            label: 'chart',
            pk: 'chart1',
        },
        variables: [
            {
                variable: {
                    name:'variable1'
                    id: 'variable1',
                    label: 'variable',
                    pk: 'variable1',
                },
                years: [
                    {
                        name:'year1'
                        id: 'year1',
                        label: 'year',
                        pk: 'year1',
                    },
                    {
                        name:'year2'
                        id: 'year2',
                        label: 'year',
                        pk: 'year2',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                variable: {
                    name:'variable2'
                    id: 'variable2',
                    label: 'variable',
                    pk: 'variable2',
                },
                years: [
                    {
                        name:'year3'
                        id: 'year3',
                        label: 'year',
                        pk: 'year3',
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        chart:{
            name: 'chart2',
            id: 'chart2',
            label: 'chart',
            pk: 'chart2',
        },
        variables: [
            {
                variable: {
                    name:'variable2'
                    id: 'variable2',
                    label: 'variable',
                    pk: 'variable2',
                },
                years: [
                    {
                        name:'year4'
                        id: 'year4',
                        label: 'year',
                        pk: 'year4',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

But with my current query:

```
g
.V()
.hasLabel('chart')
.project('chart', 'variables')
.by(valueMap(true))
.by(
    out('visualizes')
    .hasLabel('year')
    .out('outputs')
    .hasLabel('variable')
    .project('variable', 'years')
    .by(
        valueMap(true).fold()
    )
    .by(
        __.in('outputs')
        .hasLabel('year')
        .valueMap(true)
        .fold()
    )
    .fold()
)
```

This is what im getting:

```
[
    {
        chart: {
            id: 'chart1',
            label: 'chart',
            name: 'chart1',
            pk: 'chart1',
        },
        variables: [
            {
                variable: [
                    {
                        id: 'variable1',
                        label: variable,
                        name: 'variable1',
                        pk: 'variable1'
                    }
                ],
                years: [
                    {
                        id: 'year1',
                        label: 'year',
                        name: 'year1',
                        pk: 'year1',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'year2',
                        label: "year",
                        name: 'year2',
                        pk: 'year2'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                variable: [
                    {
                        id: 'variable1',
                        label: 'variable',
                        name: 'variable1',
                        'pk': 'variable1'
                    }
                ],
                years: [
                    {
                        id: 'year1',
                        label: 'year',
                        name: 'year1',
                        pk: 'year1'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'year2',
                        label: 'year',
                        name: 'year2',
                        pk: 'year2'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                variable: [
                    {
                        id: 'variable2',
                        label: "variable",
                        name: 'variable2',
                        pk: 'variable2'
                    }
                ],
                years: [
                    {
                        id: 'year3',
                        label: 'year',
                        name: 'year3',
                        pk: 'year3',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'year4',
                        label: "year",
                        name: 'year4',
                        pk: 'year4'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        chart: {
            id: 'chart2',
            label: 'chart',
            name: 'chart2',
            pk: 'chart2'
        },
        variables: [
            {
                variable: [
                    {
                        id: 'variable2',
                        label: 'variable',
                        name: 'variable2',
                        pk: 'variable2'
                    }
                ],
                years: [
                    {
                        id: 'year3',
                        label: 'year',
                        name: 'year3',
                        pk: 'year3'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'year4',
                        label: 'year',
                        name: 'year4',
                        pk: 'year4'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
//this is the formatted version to be easily read. refer to this link for the actual json: https://pastebin.com/Y2ncHyPi
```

As you can see from the actual output my problem with the query, is `chart1` duplicates `variable1` and `chart2`'s variable have `year3` which is from `chart1`. Do i have to change the structure of my graph? or do i have to add additional properties for reference? please help.

Query for seeding graph:

```
g
.addV('chart')
.property('name', 'chart1')
.property('pk', 'chart1')
.property('id', 'chart1')
.as('chart1')
.addV('chart')
.property('name', 'chart2')
.property('pk', 'chart2')
.property('id', 'chart2')
.as('chart2')

.addV('year')
.property('name', 'year1')
.property('pk', 'year1')
.property('id', 'year1')
.as('year1')
.addV('year')
.property('name', 'year2')
.property('pk', 'year2')
.property('id', 'year2')
.as('year2')
.addV('year')
.property('name', 'year3')
.property('pk', 'year3')
.property('id', 'year3')
.as('year3')
.addV('year')
.property('name', 'year4')
.property('pk', 'year4')
.property('id', 'year4')
.as('year4')

.addV('variable')
.property('name', 'variable1')
.property('pk', 'variable1')
.property('id', 'variable1')
.as('variable1')
.addV('variable')
.property('name', 'variable2')
.property('pk', 'variable2')
.property('id', 'variable2')
.as('variable2')

.addE('visualizes')
.from('chart1')
.to('year1')
.addE('outputs')
.from('year1')
.to('variable1')

.addE('visualizes')
.from('chart1')
.to('year2')
.addE('outputs')
.from('year2')
.to('variable1')

.addE('visualizes')
.from('chart1')
.to('year3')
.addE('outputs')
.from('year3')
.to('variable2')

.addE('visualizes')
.from('chart2')
.to('year4')
.addE('outputs')
.from('year4')
.to('variable2')
```

PS: I am using Azure Cosmos DB's gremlin API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a solution that I'm not sure is the simplest one, but it works:

```
g.V().hasLabel('chart').
  project('chart', 'variables').
    by(valueMap(true)).
    by(out('visualizes').
      hasLabel('year').as('y').
      out('outputs').
      group().by().
        by(select('y').fold()).unfold().
      project('variable', 'years').
        by(select(keys).
          valueMap(true)).
        by(select(values).unfold().
          valueMap(true).fold()).fold())
```

I tested it here:
https://gremlify.com/6h